# Calling the status pages in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, webserver, test

I am currently working in a project which is Linux based. From Linux terminal I have connected to our web application. The web application consists of pages and data in it so from Linux terminal I use the below command, it displays the data that is there in web application in Linux terminal:

```bash
./testclient -S ATS15X -p 14002 -itemlist ,_1,_2 -X
```

So in the above command `ATS15X` is the service name, `14002` is the port number. The `_1` & `_2` means we are calling **1st** and **2nd** pages of application.. So since we have **+100** pages in the application it would be tedious if I write as below:

```bash
./testclient -S ATS15X -p 14002 -itemlist ,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12 -X
```

So I should keep on writting till `_100`

Is there any way where I can avoid writing . I have tried _1,..,_9.. but it displays me only `1st` and `9th` page but I need to see all data from 1st to 9th page.. Can you please suggest me in modification of command or can help me how to call all the pages without writing _1 so on to _100.

Comment: It's your client! Why does it not, for example, take a `-itemrange _÷d 1 100` argument which does exactly that? Somewhere, you will have to code that list expansion, and I don't see why you're not doing it in the programming language you're comfortable enough with to write a network client in

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these:

**Solution 1**

```bash
./testclient -S ATS15X -p 14002 -itemlist "$(printf ",_%s" {1..100})" -X
```

**Solution 2 (but according to your arguments this solution would not be useful, I believe)**

```bash
./testclient -S ATS15X -p 14002 -itemlist ",_"{1..100}"" -X
#or
./testclient -S ATS15X -p 14002 -itemlist ",_"{1..100} -X
```

With the command above each field (`,_1`,`,_2`, etc) will be generated as a new argument. But, since your application takes the values `,_1,_2,_3` as **one argument** then the code above will not work, so I suggest you use the **solution 1**. 
In the case the arguments `,_1,_2,etc` had a space between each one, e.g. `,_1 ,_2 ,_3 ...` then this solution is useful.